# Combine django-filter with rangefilter

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-filter

I have an app that successfully combines single input filters such as:

- Company name
- Payment Status
- ...

All of these filters are nicely created by using the `django_filters` app ([pypi link](https://pypi.org/project/django-filter/)). Also, I can apply more than 1 filter at once, so I can search for Payments for a Specific company.

I would like to add a range filter that filters by values between 2 numbers:

- Payment Amount

To do this, I am trying to use `django-rangefilter` ([pypi link](https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-rangefilter/)) which is an extension of `django_filters`, and has specific out-of-the-box templates and functionality for Numeric Range Filters and Date Range Filters.

Problem:

- After adding the rangefilter, and submitting a filter request, the range filter clears up all of the other filters, and only applies the range filter.

Has anyone ever faced this need and problem ? What would be the least-custom-code approach recommended ? Any other modules thats could help here, noting that it must work with `django_filters` out the box.